# Overwrite code in includes folder of woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How do I overwrite functions in woocommerce/includes folder?

I have looked and I can't find a hook/filter for the specific function(save_account_details in class-wc-form-handler.php). Obviously editing that file itself also works, but id have to do it on every update.

Is there anyway to avoid having to redo the change every woocommerce update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the source for [WC_Form_Handler](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Form_Handler.html). I see this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', array( __CLASS__, 'save_account_details' ) );
```

So, you should be able to remove this with the opposite:

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', array( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'save_account_details' ) );
```

and add your own functionality with:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_function' );
```

or something along those lines.

Hope that helps